# Is there a way to select an element which has overflowed a parent element with CSS?

Tags: html, css

If I have an item with `float: right` and for whatever reason the item has appeared on the next line for reasons such as too much content to the left of it, or the window is too small; how do I select items which match this case?

I wish to do this as the parent item uses a background image which looks fine, but it the floated item falls out it does not appear visible as the `color` and `background-color` are both the same.

is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to use javascript and detect relative position of the floated div. If this one has a y coordinate greater than 0, it has probably fall. Add a css class or whatever behavior you want in this case.